# Is ‘mind me to sit’ right?

Tags: grammar

1. Do you mind me to sit here?
2. Do you mind my sitting here?

I know the second sentence is right, but can you tell why the first sentence is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

That's because the question is **not about someone having an object to *you* but an action of yours.** That is why 'my' is necessary.

> Do you mind *my sitting* here?

Furthermore, "Do you mind if I sit here?" seems *okay* as well and probably more common. Nevertheless, in my opinion, better (and even politer) is replacing "can" with "may."

> *May* I sit here?

Comment: Do you mind me to sit here?  Is it a right sentence?

Comment: @Y.zeng: No, it isn't.